# Convert dta files in csv

Tags: python, r, csv

I want to convert several dta files into csv. 
So far my code is (to be honest I used an answer I found on stackoverflow...)

```
library(foreign)

setwd("C:\Users\Victor\Folder") 

for (f in Sys.glob('*.dta')) 
    write.csv(read.dta(f), file = gsub('dta$', 'csv', f))
```

It works, but if my folder contains sub-folders they are ignored.
My problem is that I have 11 sub-folders (which may contain sub-folders themselves) I would like to find a way to loop my folder and sub-folders, because right now I need to change my working directory for each sub-folders and.

I'm using R now, I tried to use pandas (python) but it seems that the quality of the conversion is debatable...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In R to do this you just set `recursive = T` in `list.files`.

Actually, specifying recursion when dealing with directories is kind of general -- it works with command line operations in OS's including Linux and Windows with commands like `rm -rf` and applies to multiple functions in R.

This post has a nice example:

[How to use R to Iterate through Subfolders and bind CSV files of the same ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169446/how-to-use-r-to-iterate-through-subfolders-and-bind-csv-files-of-the-same-id)

Their example (which is different only in what they're doing with the results of the directory/subdirectory search) is:

```
 lapply(c('1234' ,'1345','1456','1560'),function(x){
     sources.files  <- list.files(path=TF,
                                recursive=T,
                                pattern=paste('*09061*',x,'*.csv',sep='')
                                ,full.names=T)
      ## You read all files with the id and bind them
      dat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(sources.files,read.csv))
      ### write the file for the 
      write(dat,paste('agg',x,'.csv',sep='')
   }
```

So for you `pattern = '.dta'` and just set your base directory in `path`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using base R's [list.files()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/list.files) as the *recursive* argument specifies to search in subdirectories. You will also want *full.names* set to return absolute paths for file referencing.

So, set your pattern to look for `.dta` extensions (i.e., Stata datasets) and then run the read in and write out function:

```
import foreign

statafiles <- list.files("C:\\Users\\Victor\\Folder", pattern="\\.dta$", 
                         recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

lapply(statafiles, function(x) {
     df <- read.dta(x)
     write.csv(df, gsub(".dta", ".csv", x))
})
```

And the counterpart in Python pandas which has built-in methods to [read and write stata files](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html):

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\Victor\\Folder"):
    for f in files:        
        if f.endswith(".dta"):
            df = pd.read_stata(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
            df.to_csv(os.path.join(dirpath, f.replace(".dta", ".csv")))
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. When I try you code there's an error : ' Error: unexpected '}' in "}" ' . Also is pandas ok to read stata files ? I code it in python but it was pretty slow, that's why I use R hopping it would be quicker !

Comment: Can't see why you receive error all braces and parentheses close properly. Did you highlight entire lapply? Try either for performance. All depends on data amount, number of files, etc. For csv conversion, I cannot imagine they differ much or even that they go *pretty slow*.